# Can I use real currency name/symbol as an in-game currency?

Tags: android, google-play

Can I use a real currency name (i.e USD, PKR) or symbol ($, Rs.) for my in-game currency with the same exchange value as original currency? I couldn't find anything about it in google play store policies neither in government websites.

Of course I have other options, I can call it gold or silver etc but I'm just wondering if it is allowed or not.

Comment: This seems like a question you can answer for yourself with just a little research of existing games. For instance, the Grand Theft Auto games use dollars with the $ sign, even in their Android versions. In the face of this positive evidence, do you have any evidence that would suggest this is *not* allowed?

Comment: Since you mentioned exchange value, is your in-game currency bought with real money?

Comment: @DMGregory read the question carefully. GTA using dollar sign but they aren't using the same exchange rate and currency name (i.e USD). I also did the research on existing games and there are alot of games which aren't using $ alone, like roblox.

Comment: @milk yes. with real money as well as with rewarded videos. It's also encashable means user would be able to withdraw it.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib This sounds way too complicated for a simple game. If you want users to be able to deposit and withdraw money of different currencies, and keep the exchange rate up to date, I strongly suggest you consult a professional.

Comment: +1 to TomTsagk. If you want to be able to withdraw money then I don't think the crux of this is game related. If you really want to support withdrawing money, I suggest speaking with lawyers on how to legally create a financial institution, otherwise you may be seen as doing something illegal such as creating a platform to launder money.

Comment: This is definitely a legal question.. There's other StackExchange sites for this kind of question.. A short answer though, is that at least in the US, I would entirely assume it's illegal _not_ to tell me what kind of currency, or how much that you're charging me or giving me. Also what you're describing is called a country code currency symbol, and there's no sort of trademark or something on "USD", it's designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: This would also be considered a gambling game in the US, and you need a special legal license to be able to run any such game in the US. You might be able to find more information about that sort of license by asking your question, with this added to it, in a law/legal advice Stack Exchange.

Comment: Dear All, as you suggested speaking with lawyers, this is exactly what I am looking for, the developers who have already deal with this type of requirements before in law and regulations way.